# how to make cart item stay for 24hrs after logout in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a shopping cart which is working fine but if a user doesn't place an order,then after logout the cart item doesn't stays.So can anyone help how to make the cart items stay for at least 1 day. I am not using any database,here's want i have done:

```
   if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;
        dt.Columns.Add("sno");
        dt.Columns.Add("Game_Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Platform");
        dt.Columns.Add("Price");
        dt.Columns.Add("Quantity");
        dt.Columns.Add("Image");
        dt.Columns.Add("cost");
        dt.Columns.Add("totalcost");
        //BindGridView();

        if (Request.QueryString["Game_ID"] != null)
        {
            if (Session["Buyitems"] == null)
            {

                dr = dt.NewRow();
                String mycon = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(mycon);
                String myquery = "select * from Game where Game_ID=" + Request.QueryString["Game_ID"];
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = myquery;
                cmd.Connection = scon;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                dr["sno"] = 1;                   
                dr["Game_Name"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Game_Name"].ToString();
                dr["Platform"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Platform"].ToString();
                dr["Image"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Image"].ToString();
                dr["Price"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Price"].ToString();
                dr["Quantity"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Quantity"].ToString();

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                Session["buyitems"] = dt;
            }
            else
            {

                dt = (DataTable)Session["buyitems"];
                int sr;
                sr = dt.Rows.Count;

                dr = dt.NewRow();
                String mycon = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(mycon);
                String myquery = "select * from Game where Game_ID=" + Request.QueryString["Game_ID"];
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = myquery;
                cmd.Connection = scon;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                dr["sno"] = sr + 1;                    
                dr["Game_Name"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Game_Name"].ToString();
                dr["Platform"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Platform"].ToString();
                dr["Image"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Image"].ToString();
                dr["Price"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Price"].ToString();
                dr["Quantity"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Quantity"].ToString();

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                Session["buyitems"] = dt;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            dt = (DataTable)Session["buyitems"];
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            }

    }
```

and i m using command argument to fetch the id of each game from previous page.

Comment: You say after logout so I assume the user logs in, just bind the cart to the account. Make a database table called cart and cartToProduct or something, then just set an expiration date on the cart

Answer (score 0):

If you store in cookie, set them to expire after 24 hours.
You can maintain the cart add time and remove it through the job or manually when check and remove when you fetch the items from database.

Comment: You can simple store it in DOM, for example read this https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38159/localstorage-setexpire-code-to-add-time-expires

Comment: how can i store it in cookie,in the above code mentioned.can you give an example?

Comment: @SuvenduBhattacharjee you can follow habeeb's code to do same.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cookies to save the Shopping Cart for later use. This is the option if user adds items to card even without login.

```
public void SaveCart2Cookie(List<string> items) 
{
    string cartList = string.Join(",", items);

    if (Request.Cookies["CartCookie"] == null)
        Response.Cookies["CartCookie"].Value = cartList;
    else
    {
        Create new Cart Cookie
    }

    Response.Cookies["CartCookie"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either use cookies or if you are targeting users with modern browsers you could also use `Web Storage API` which you'll have to control using the client side code.

I'd suggest you add some code to your question so we can provide better answers.